# Why in java answer for a is 2.0 but i think it should be 2.5. double a = 1.0 + 2 * 3 / 4;

Tags: java

Why in java answer for variable a is 2.0 but I think it should be 2.5 and also google said 2.5 .

```
double a = 1.0 + 2 * 3 / 4;
```

Comment: `2 * 3 / 4` as integers is 0

Comment: @Joseph Actually, it's 1. `2 * 3` is evaluated first.

Comment: @Tunaki Oops, right you are. I actually for some reason thought it was floored integer division, and my brain replaced 1.0 with 2.0...